# C++: How can I look at the next character of a file I'm reading in to compare the characters?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have to read from a file one character at a time (can't read it using a string!) and if I find a `//` then I must ignore everything until I get to the end of the line.

Comment: You could always `get` it and then `unget` if you don't want it.

Comment: `=` is for assignment, not for equality comparison (`==`).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ whoops I made a mistake when typing it on here lol

Comment: @tadman I havent learned get and unget, I'll look it up. Hopefully it works!

Comment: @przm you typed your code here ?? Why don't you copy paste it ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz it usually looks super weird when I copy it on here from visual studios so I just re-type it lol

Comment: @tadman did I use `unget` properly above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a state machine, I note that the ifstream class has a `peek()` method that you could use to look-ahead one character without needing to get then put back

Comment: How would I write it using a peek()? I tried `if (c == '/' && infile.peek(c) == '/')` but that doesn't work

Comment: You really need to get c first.  `c = infile.get(); if ( (c=='/')&&(infile.peek()=='/')  ){ while ( c != '\n') { c= infile.get() /* consume the comment */ } }`

Comment: @infixed Editing the question was a bad idea. It changed the nature of the question dramatically. I recommend reverting the edit and asking a new question.

Comment: Changed it back, sorry!

Comment: um, I didn't edit the question.   But not seeing what it was before the revert, I suspect there may be problems in how end of files are being handled too.   I'm pretty sure that original outer while loop does not make a 'while not end of file' construct.  Or a 'while stream good' one.You may want to look at the docs for istream again, especially noting the eof() and good() methods.  Don't forget you'll need error handling every place you read a char, including the inner loop

Answer (score 5):

Use a state machine. You have three states:

1) **Normal**: This is the state you start in. You advance to state 2 if you read a `/`. Otherwise, process the character you read and stay in this state.

2) **Read one `/`**: In this state, if you read a `/`, you go state 3. Otherwise, process a `/`, process the character you just read, then go to state 1.

3) **Read two '/`'s**: In this state, you ignore what you read unless it's a newline. If it's a newline, you go to state 1. (You may or may not need to process the newline depending on the details of your application.)

Comment: It's just as simple as `int state =1;` .. `if (state == 1) { if (char_read == '/') state = 2; else process_char(char_read); if (state == 2) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically, since you are not doing anything with the characters at all at the moment, you are ignoring everything, which includes the stuff after //

But consider using a state variable, like an enum with values `{ OK, COMMENTTRIGGER, COMMENTACTIVE}`
Normally be in state OK.

On the first `/` (i.e `((state==OK && (c=='/')) )` , change state to COMMENTTRIGGER

on the second `/` ( i.e. `((state==COMMENTTRIGGER)&&(c=='/') )`, change state to COMMENTACTIVE.

If you are in the COMMENTTRIGGER state, and you DON'T get the second `/`, revert to state OK, and handle the previous`/` before handling the new character.  Because its a singular `/`

When you get to newline, set the state back to OK, because you want to handle things again

Ignore stuff when in state COMMENTACTIVE